# How to find M10 when connected to Ubuntu desktop by USB?

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, bq, aquaris, m10

Connecting Aquaris M10 to Ubuntu desktop with USB, it appears in file manager, but no contents shown. Can view microSD contents when ejected from the tablet. 
Is it possible to get to the M10's contents from the Ubuntu desktop via the USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe the solution to this problem to have been to update the software on the tablet. Tablet had not been visible to the desktop when connected by USB. After updates to the tablet, it became visible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely a supported feature of Ubuntu Touch which works on M10.

Screenshot of how it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of how it looks like.]

So it should work... Why it doesn't?.. I can suggest only one thing for you to check. Ubuntu Touch must be logged in before you can see the contents on the desktop. Otherwise you will see only the device name ("Aquaris M10 FHD" in my case, see the screenshot) in the list of disks without any contents.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. When you say "Ubuntu Touch must be logged in...", I am not sure what you mean. I am logged into the tablet and I am logged into the desktop. What am I missing?